# Webpack 2 not reloading when changing javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to webpack 2 and I am not able to figure out why my file is not updating and browser is not reloading when I change it.

This is screenshot of my webpack config. Please help :(

[image]

Comment: How are you executing `webpack`?

Comment: I managed to fixed it. Thank you. FYI: I am starting my server like "webpack-dev-server --hot"

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` for hot reloading.

Please refer the (webpack.config.js)[https://github.com/abhiisheek/angular1-x-webpack-strater/blob/master/webpack.config.js] for achiving it.

Comment: I just made it work by adding this to my webpack.config file

`output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },`

Comment: @SenadMetiljevic Is hot reload also working without the plugin ?

Comment: Yes it is. I am starting my server like "webpack-dev-server --hot" and getting message in the console "[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled."

Comment: @SenadMetiljevic That might be another solution like the above one. What do you say ?

Comment: Didn't try ur solution but this one works for me perfectly! Thank you for your time.